# Проблема с добавлением шаблона электронного письма в django

Tags: python, html, django

я делаю систему регистрации на сайте, и остался последний шаг - отправка кода подтверждения на email.

```
views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.template.loader import get_template
import django
import random
import string
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def registration(request):
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'Пользователь с данным адресом уже зарегестрирован!')
        else:
            if form.is_valid():

                ins = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password, email=email)
                ins.email = email
                ins.save()
                form.save_m2m()
                login(request, user)    
                send_mail('DjiSoc - Регистрация', 'blala', "DjiSoc",
                [email], fail_silently=False, html_message=get_template('authorization/email.html'))
                
                
                
            

    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authorization/registration.html', context)



def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')


email.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 45px; background-color: #D9A6B1;">
            Текст
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

В чем суть вопроса: на этапе отправки письма выдает ошибку: AttributeError at /auth/registration/
'Template' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
D:\Work\Python\Django\Dev\DjiSoc_General\authorization\views.py in registration
[email], fail_silently=False, html_message=get_template('authorization/email.html')) …
▶ Local vars

В чем проблема, весь интернет уже обшарил?

Comment: Значение `html_message` обязано быть строкой, а вы туда запихнули объект шаблона вместо строки

Comment: а как мне тогда по другому сделать красивое письмо с использованием html/css?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547